# Self join get records comparing data from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables `SchoolMembers` and `SchoolDetails`

SchoolMembers

```
School  SchoolMember
KGB1    KGB1
KGB1    KGB2
KGB1    KGB3
```

and SchoolDetails

```
id  schoolMember  type            YearJoining   PeriodJoining
136 KGB1          Principal       2016          17001
137 KGB2          SubPrinciple    2016          17001
138 KGB1          SubPrinciple    2016          17001
139 KGB3          Teacher         2016          17004
140 KGB4          Teacher         2018          17004
```

I have to get school member for all Schools which is having SchoolDetails type teacher having Yearjoining or period joining after Principle.

I am unsure about how to do this, I tried this using self join but no luck.

Expected result as 139 has period greater than Principal.

```
139 KGB3    Teacher 2016    17004
```

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: You should have both 138 and 140 right?

Comment: No, as KGB4        is not member of SchoolMembers  for school KGB1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below query.

```
SELECT *
FROM SchoolMembers SM1
    INNER JOIN SchoolDetails SD1
        ON SD1.schoolMember = SM1.schoolMember AND SD1.type = 'teacher'
    INNER JOIN SchoolMembers SM2
        ON SM1.School = SM2.School
    INNER JOIN SchoolDetails SD2
        ON SD2.schoolMember = SM2.schoolMember AND SD2.type = 'Principal'
WHERE SD1.YearJoining > SD2.YearJoining
    OR SD1.PeriodJoining > SD2.PeriodJoining
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select SD1.id,SM.schoolMember,SD1.type,SD1.YearJoining,SD1.PeriodJoining from 
SchoolMembers SM
inner join SchoolDetails SD1
on (SM1.schoolMember = SD.schoolMember)
inner join SchoolDetails SD2
on (SD1.id = SD2.id)
where (SD1.YearJoining > SD2.YearJoining) 
  or(SD1.PeriodJoining > SD2.PeriodJoining );
```